# Put email multiple folder in case of multiple recipients using procmail

Tags: procmail

I'm going to build an email system at home and I'm subscribed to a lot of mailing list. The emails fetched to my local machine by fetchmail and filtered by procmail. But, there is a situation which is not possible to solve with my current knowledge. I have been googling for 2-3 hours to find a solution without any result.

What I want is that, I get an email with multiple recipients and I would like to copy this email to different folders. Here is an example:

```
Cc: linux-kernel@vger.kernel.org, kernel-janitors@vger.kernel.org
```

I would like to put this email into linux-kernel and linux-kernel-janitors folder. How can I do it by procmail?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make Procmail loop on the list of recipients by using `SWITCHRC=` but this is rather hackish.  Or, if you have a limited list of folders you want to process, you can deliver into each separately, and drop the message if you have delivered it at least once.

```
LASTFOLDER=
:0c:
* ^TO_linux-kernel@vger\.kernel\.org\>
linux-kernel
:0c:
* ^TO_kernel-janitors@vger\.kernel\.org\>
kernel-janitors
# ... repeat for other addresses you want to multiplex ...
# If it was delivered, LASTFOLDER will be set
:0
* LASTFOLDER ?? .
/dev/null
```

If you may have copied into additional inboxes before reaching this section, you want to explicitly set `LASTFOLDER` to the empty string.  It should not be necessary otherwise, but I left it in as a precaution.  (This variable contains the name of the latest folder the message was delivered to.)

Comment: My first attempt at an answer was rather off the mark, so I just want to point out that if you read my reply immediately after I wrote it, you might want to revisit.  Sorry about that.

Comment: You are right it seems a little bit hackish but I think it can solve my issue. I'm going to take a try and I will inform you here about the result. Thank you very much your help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution looks like this:

First of all, an If statement is needed because my .procmailrc file contains not just kernel mailing list filter conditions. If it matches than there is another list of conditions. I think by the time it will be more fine-grained.

```
:0
 * [To|Cc].*vger.kernel.org
   LASTFOLDER=

    :0Ac:
    * ^[To|Cc].*linux-janitors@vger.kernel.org
    | DoItSomethingWithIt

    :0Ac:
    * ^[To|Cc].*linux-kernel@vger.kernel.org
    | DoItSomethingWithIt2

    :0                             
    * LASTFOLDER ?? .
    | DoItSomethingWithIt3
```

Comment: The regex `[To|Cc]` is incorrect, it matches a single character from the enumerated set `T` `o` `|` `c` (I'm omitting the uppercase C because matching is case-insensitive). I think you want the special macro `^TO_` like in my response.

Comment: Oh, and for a pipe action, you need a named lockfile, or no lockfile at all. In other words, the second colon on the delivering actions is wrong, either way. http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#locking